# How to ensure log the exception when there is unhandled exception

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want a crash reporting, so I register the UnhandledException event in App.xaml.cs like following. But there are 2 problems:

1. Sometimes, there is no callstacks for exception
2. Sometimes, I don't have enough time to write log into file before the process is terminated.

Any advice?

```
this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
```

```
private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!hasHandledUnhandledException)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        _logger.Error("Unhandle exception - message = {0}\n StackTrace = {1}", e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace);
        await CrashHandler.ReportExceptionAsync(e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace);
        hasHandledUnhandledException = true;
        throw e.Exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: Log `e.Exception.ToString()` instead of separating the message from the stack trace.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't think so, since the logging takes place before the async call. Though I guess I'm speculating about what `CrashHandler.ReportExceptionAsync` really does. I'm thinking about something UI related

Comment: @KooKiz, CrashHandler.ReportExceptionAsync  just writes file exception to the file.

Comment: @yuxhu Then you have a problem. You need to find a synchronous way to write into the file, because the method will return when you call `await`, and your app will be terminated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to access `e.Exception` only once. In some cases, [information about the stacktrace is lost the second time you access the property](http://blog.wpdev.fr/inspecting-unhandled-exceptions-youve-got-only-one-chance/). Save the exception in a variable and work directly with that variable. Also, as mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos in the comments, directly log `e.Exception.ToString()` to make sure to miss no information. This will include the message, the callstack, and all inner exceptions (which you are not logging in your current code).

```
private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!hasHandledUnhandledException)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var exception = e.Exception;
        _logger.Error("Unhandled exception - {0}", exception);
        await CrashHandler.ReportExceptionAsync(exception.Message, exception.StackTrace);
        hasHandledUnhandledException = true;
        throw e.Exception;
    }
}
```

As for the problem of not having enough time to log the exception, it's controlled by the runtime so you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks @KooKiz, I will try it.

Comment: I can get the call stack now. Thank you!